# NodeJs on Router via DD-WRT or OpenWRT?

Tags: linux, node.js, openwrt, dd-wrt

Know anybody, how i can install NodeJS on dd-wrt, openwrt or freewrt system?

Or Maybe on any Router with one on these systems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_or_firewall_distributions

Comment: https://github.com/brimstone/nodejs-openwrt  found this

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across one fellow on Twitter who [claimed to have done so](https://twitter.com/revin/status/55276069082759168) back in 2011 April and [offered a high-level overview of the process](https://twitter.com/revin/status/223166695479590912). My research indicates that this will only be possible on little-endian chipsets (e.g. "mipsel", as on the ASUS RT-N16) as even the MIPS version of v8 [does not support big-endian](https://github.com/paul99/v8m-rb/issues/3#issuecomment-4500448) implementations of that architecture (e.g. as the Atheros chipset on the Buffalo WZR-HP-AG300H is using).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, couldn't find any references that indicate it's been done. I suggest checking out the dependencies for Node.

You will need at least the following:

- gcc4-g++
- git
- make
- pkg-config
- zlib-devel
- openssl-devel
- openssl
- python

Note, that is from the older [Cygwin compile instructions](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-%28Windows%29) so they might not be exactly right.

If you can find all of those for your router OS then it should be possible. Just note that it will take a LONG time to compile.

You may also struggle with memory as most routers are severely lacking. [This question on Google](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nodejs/MnQmSwZkh3k) has a bit of information.

Comment: I was thinking about building ruby for my openwrt. I have an exmaple for C code here:
http://eggie5.com/40-cross-compile-mips-openwrt